# Nonzero element positions of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, sparse-arrays

Let

```
m={{1, 2, 0}, {4, 0, 9}};
```

I want to find the position of every nonzero element of the above matrix. The code

```
SparseArray[m]["NonzeroPositions"]
```

returns

```
{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}}
```

I want the output will be something like this

```
{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}
```

that is every element of the output is a list of the corresponding columns of nonzero elements in each row. How do I modify the code?

Comment: `GatherBy[SparseArray[m]["NonzeroPositions"], First][[All, All, 2]]`

Comment: or `(SparseArray[#]["NonzeroPositions"] & /@ m)[[;; , ;; , 1]]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:** The property `"AdjacencyLists"` gives what you need:

```
SparseArray[m]["AdjacencyLists"]
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}}

This approach, unlike the one using `GatherBy` in the original post, gives the empty set `{}` for the rows consisting entirely of zeros:

```
SparseArray[{{1, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 9}}]["AdjacencyLists"]
```

> {{1, 2}, {}, {1, 3}}

**Original post:**

```
m = {{1, 2, 0}, {4, 0, 9}};
sa = SparseArray[m]["NonzeroPositions"];
GatherBy[sa, First][[All, All, -1]]
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}}

Answer (score 3):

If the matrix isn't that sparse, then `Pick` may be a more efficient idea:

```
Pick[Range@Length@m[[1]], #, 0] & /@ UnitStep@-m
```

Answer (score 2):

```
m = {{1, 2, 0}, {4, 0, 9}};

Flatten @* Values @* KeyDrop[0] @* PositionIndex /@ m
```

{1, 2}, {1, 3}}

Answer (score 2):

**Using SequencePosition:**

```
First /@ SequencePosition[#, {Except[0]}] & /@ m
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}}

Answer (score 1):

One can use e.g.  `SplitBy[list, First]` way:

```
SplitBy[ SparseArray[m]["NonzeroPositions"], First][[All, 2]]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Position`, `Condition` and `Table`:

```
f = Table[Flatten@Position[#[[i]], x_ /; x != 0], {i, Length@#}] &;

f@m

(*{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}*)
```

Or using `Position`, `Condition` and `Range`:

```
Flatten@*Transpose /@ (Position[m[[#]], x_ /; x != 0] & /@ Range[Length@m])

(*{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}*)
```